# How to generate several data frames from each row of a single data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the following (which contains 100 rows, here I have given only 6).

```
CTFIP   Hispanic    Non Hispanic
6001    323307  1154673
6003    63      1113
6005    4566    33761
6007    29512   189123
6009    4595    41399
6011    11136   10029
```

I want to generate different data frame for each row which should be like this

```
HISPn   Freq
1      323307
2     11154673
```

Where 1= Hispanic, 2= Non-hispanic

How can I generate these data frames in R?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution using `tidyr` and `dplyr`. First, the sample data.frame

```
dd<-read.table(text="CTFIP   Hispanic    NonHispanic
6001    323307  1154673
6003    63  1113
6005    4566    33761
6007    29512   189123
6009    4595    41399
6011    11136   10029", header=T)
```

then

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dd %>% gather(ethnicity, freq, -CTFIP) %>% 
    mutate(HISPn=ifelse(ethnicity=="Hispanic", 1,2)) %>%
    select(HISPn, freq)
```

which returns

```
   HISPn    freq
1      1  323307
2      1      63
3      1    4566
4      1   29512
5      1    4595
6      1   11136
7      2 1154673
8      2    1113
9      2   33761
10     2  189123
11     2   41399
12     2   10029
```

If you want a list of a bunch of different data frames (which sounds like a bad idea), you can do

```
dd %>% gather(ethnicity, freq, -CTFIP) %>% 
    mutate(HISPn=ifelse(ethnicity=="Hispanic", 1,2)) %>%
    select(CTFIP , freq, HISPn) %>%
    {split(., .$CTFIP)}
```

which returns

```
$`6001`
  CTFIP    freq HISPn
1  6001  323307     1
7  6001 1154673     2
$`6003`
  CTFIP freq HISPn
2  6003   63     1
8  6003 1113     2
...
```

Comment: I need data frame for each row not summation of all rows. Thank you

Comment: Make sure you have `tidyr` installed.

Comment: For some reasons I can't install the tidyr. BTW, the result given here are based on the summation of each columns. But I need different data frames for each row.

Comment: I've updated my response which creates a list of a bunch of data.frames. However that seems like a very unfriendly data format.

Answer (score 0):

The tidyr solution will create one giant data.frame where the columns have been transformed into rows.  If you really need separate data.frames for each row, then I think you really want a loop.  But -- are you **sure** you really need separate data.frames for each row?  My experience has been, every time I thought this, there was an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in `base R` if you have only `100 rows`

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) 
       data.frame(HISPn=1:2, Freq=unlist(df[i,-1], use.names=FALSE))), 
                                                  paste0('df', df$CTFIP))
```

It is better to have it as a list of data.frames.  But, if you need separate `data.frame` objects in the global environment.

```
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

df6001
# HISPn    Freq
#1     1  323307
#2     2 1154673
```

Or you could use `reshape` from `base R`

```
colnames(df)[-1] <- paste('Freq', 1:2, sep='.')
dfL <- reshape(df, direction='long', idvar='CTFIP', 
                             varying=2:3, timevar='HISPn')
row.names(dfL) <- NULL
lst1 <- split(dfL[,-1], df$CTFIP)
names(lst1) <- paste0('df', names(lst1))
list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
df6001
#  HISPn    Freq
#1     1  323307
#7     2 1154673
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(CTFIP = c(6001L, 6003L, 6005L, 6007L, 6009L, 6011L
), Hispanic = c(323307L, 63L, 4566L, 29512L, 4595L, 11136L), 
Non.Hispanic = c(1154673L, 1113L, 33761L, 189123L, 41399L, 
10029L)), .Names = c("CTFIP", "Hispanic", "Non.Hispanic"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```